# Implement preferences menu entry in MacCatalyst

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I have an app which uses SwiftUI and Mac Catalyst. When running on a Mac I want to provide a preferences menu entry with the usual keyboard shortcut Command + ,. An implementation via the Settings bundle is out of question since my preferences are too complex for this.

Here is a reduced example of my implementation:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct PreferencesMenuTestApp: App {
  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor private var appDelegate: AppDelegate
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
  }
}


class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  
  override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    let preferencesCommand = UIKeyCommand(title: "Preferences…",
                                          action: #selector(showPreferences),
                                          input: ",",
                                          modifierFlags: .command)
    
//    let preferencesCommand = UIAction(title: "Preferences…") { action in
//      debugPrint("show preferences")
//    }
    
    let menu = UIMenu(title: "Preferences…",
                      options: .displayInline,
                      children: [preferencesCommand])
    
    builder.insertSibling(menu, afterMenu: .about)
  }
  
  
  @objc
  func showPreferences() {
    debugPrint("show preferences")
  }
}
```

The problem is that the menu entry is disabled. Obviously the provided selector is not recognised. When I mark the `AppDelegate` with `@main`, then the menu entry is enabled. Of course then the app's window is empty.
When I switch to the `UIAction` implementation (the out commented code) it works fine. But since one cannot provide a keyboard shortcut for `UIAction`s this is not a good solution.

What am I missing? How would one implement a preferences menu entry that actually works?

Comment: Why use SwiftUI and Mac Catalyst? Why not build the SwiftUI app as a native macOS app? Then you can use the `Settings` scene.

Comment: It is a universal app for iOS, watchOS and macOS (Catalyst).

Comment: Right. That's one of the main benefits of SwiftUI. The same code works on all platforms (with a few minor OS-specific tweaks where needed). If you built your SwiftUI as a native macOS app then you wouldn't need a UIAppDelegate or UIMenu to get built-in support for the preferences menu simply by adding the `Settings` scene.

Answer (score 0):

Since this a catalyst app, some object in your responder chain needs to respond to `showPreferences` method. These objects are generally ViewControllers or your application instance - all of which inherit from UIResponder. Based on the information you provided, I am guessing that your AppDelegate may need to provide these methods:

```
    // MARK: Responder chain stuff
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(showPreferences) {
            return true
        } 
        return super.responds(to: aSelector)
    }

    @objc
    func showPreferences() {
        //do something like start a new scene with your preferences
    }
```